# Swift Google SDK slow when user location is turned on

Tags: ios, swift

Im currently using google Maps for a project, whenever user location is turned on my cpu jump up to nearly 70 percent. when user location is off everything is normal and cpu is not high. Is this normal for google maps. my screen does lag so im assumming this cannot be normal. can i get any advice on how to make maps run faster and avoid these cpu hikes. thank you

```
//my initializer
   lazy var mapView:GMSMapView = {
        var v = GMSMapView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
```

without user location

[image: without user Location]
with user location

[image: with user locaion here]

Comment: Hey, you found any solution? I am also facing same issue. Google Map screen making my application slow.